# mesg y command not working

Tags: tty

Despite using `mesg y`, the `?` next to both the **username** is not changing to `+` because of which I'm not able to use `write/wall` command

```
shaunx333@Aspire:~$ who -w
tempuser ? :0           2021-06-25 13:27 (:0)
shaunx333 ? :1           2021-06-25 13:27 (:1)
```

Is there any way to change it to `+` ?

`

Comment: Can you please edit the question so we can understand what you are asking?

Comment: It is an interesting question, but needs to be fleshed out quite a bit to be understandble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon that is hinted at in the question is the following. Users on a multiuser Linux system are able to write messages to each other using the `write` command. The message would show up on the console. Also, a `root` user would be able to send a message to all users at once using the `wall` command.

If you are busy, you may turn off these messages by entering the command `mesg n`, and turn them back on with `mesg y`. The default is `y`.

To show which users are logged on, and which are listening to messages, you can use the `who -w` command. It will show a `+` for users who allow messages to come through, and a `-` for those who don't. If the system can't determine what the `mesg` status of the user is, it will display a `?`.

These days most of us will use a graphic environment and a terminal emulator, rather than a text console. A terminal emulator establishes what is called a "pseudo tty device". The `who` command (you can find its source by searching for the `coreutils` package) tries, but fails, to determine the `mesg` state of a pseudo tty device.

However, if you open a different console, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, and login, the `who -w` command will display:

```
jos      + tty3         2021-06-25 10:52
```

This is a genuine `tty` device and not a pseudoterminal. Notice the `+` that indicates I'm prepared to read messages from my co-users *on this console*.

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding my problem and sorry for not able to describe the problem clearly

Comment: If you feel my answer to your question was helpful, please tick the box next to it.

Comment: @shaunx333 And even now you can always edit the question for future use(rs)